# How can I capitalize all words in a sentence using a function?

Tags: c

I want to enlarge the initials of the words in the sentence I entered. The program does not give any errors, I think I have logical errors.

It is my input.

```
the weather is sunny today.
```

It is output.

```
t
```

The output that I want.

```
The Weather İs Sunny Today.
```

My codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

char grow(char sentence []);
int main() {
    int i,j;
    char result[100],sentence[100];
    printf("please enter your sentence");
    gets(sentence);
    result[i]=grow(sentence);
    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
}
char grow(char sentence[]){
    int i,length;
    char result[100];
    
    length=strlen(sentence);
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        
        if(sentence[i]==' '){
            sentence[i+1]=toupper(sentence[i+1]);
            
        }
    return(sentence[i]);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: `=='\0'` does not mean "empty space", but "the end of the string". Empty space is just `' '`

Comment: In `result[i]=grow(sentence);` the `int i` has not been initialised. Aside: please don't make "live" updates to the code - just post the code you are asking about.

Comment: I fixed it, but the results did not change.@SJuan76

Comment: You should not use conio and gets

Comment: `char grow` should be `char* grow`, `return(sentence[i]);` should be `return sentence;`

Comment: Since I am working with a string I need to use this.@Davide

Comment: if (sentence[i]==32 && sentence[++i]!=‘\0’)                         sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be cleaned up a lot, see the included comments:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// for the toupper function
#include <ctype.h>
// no conio.h since it's non-standard

// this is void since the function doesn't need to return anything
void grow(char sentence []);
int main() {
    // no int i,j since you don't need them
    // no result array needed since it modifies in place
    char sentence[100];
    printf("please enter your sentence\n");
    // fgets instead of gets for security reasons
    fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);
    // no result[i]= at start of line since function modifies in place
    grow(sentence);
    printf("%s", sentence);
    return 0;
}

// this is void for same reasons as above
void grow(char sentence[]){
    // don't need strlen to loop through the string twice
    // you can just make sure you're not on a nullbyte
    for(int i = 0; sentence[i]; i++){
        // check previous character or index 0 instead
        if(i == 0 || sentence[i - 1] == ' ') {
            // capitalize current character to avoid out of bounds write
            sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your own sake you should stop using Turbo C.

Here is a much simpler algorithm. Simplicity leads to more readability which leads to less bugs and greater ease for making improvemets

```
while( scanf(" %s", word) == 1 ) {
    
    toupper(word[0]);
    printf("%s ", word);
}
```